# textures in blender are not showing up in unity (vrchat model)

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I'm trying to upload a vrchat model I used vroid to make the model and added it to blender to convert it to be added to unity but when it's on unity there are no textures on the model they are all gray. images attached    [blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luzPo.jpg)   [unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwRsL.png)

im new to this and need help

Answer (score 0):

You should export textures and materials in unity.

[image: First select model from your project then export textures and materials]